# Typescript 'disable' excess property checking

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In typescript I have the following `type`:

```
type Base = {
  mandatoryProperty: number
}
```

Then I would like to create a `Full type` starting from `Base` that EITHER has a `property1: number` or `property2: number`, such as:

```
type Full = {
  mandatoryProperty: number
  property1: number
} | {
  mandatoryProperty: number
  property2: number
}
```

I create a `Combined` utility `type`:

```
type Combined<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof V]: {[R in keyof T]: T[R]} & { [P in K]: V[P] }
}[keyof V]
```

And lastly:

```
type Full = Combined<Base, {property1: number, property2: number}>
```

This type has the structure I expect it to have, yet, I can do something like this:

```
const X: Full = {
  mandatoryProperty: 3,
  property1: 2,
  property2: 4
}
```

I only want either property1 or property2 to be within the `type`. Not both. If I understand correctly, this occurs because of typescript's excess property checking behaviour. How can I force it to not occur?

EDIT:

As @jcalz mentioned, one way to achieve the desired behaviour is to set unwanted properties to `never`. I try doing so by changing the `type` to:

```
type Combined<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof V]: {[R in keyof T]: T[R]} & { [S in keyof V]: S extends K ? V[K] : never }
}[keyof V];
```

But this doesn't work. What is the reason?

Comment: You want to *enforce* excess property checking everywhere, not disable it. But TS doesn't have that. If you want an exclusive union you need to write it like `{property1: number, property2?: never} | {property1?: never, property2: number}` or have TS compute it for you by defining an `ExclusifyUnion` utility type as described in the answer to the linked question above.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the swift answer. I've read the original question and understood how to achieve the desired result. Yet I have another question. Why setting the undesired properties to `never` as in the edit does not work? Thanks.

Comment: I mean, if you modify the question after the fact it's not going to get much attention, and if you only say "this doesn't work" instead of describing the actual problem, then it's not a [mre]. My guess is that you need the property to be optional for `never` to "work", but I don't know what the problem is and this question, as asked originally, has already been addressed. Not sure how to proceed form here.